# Drop down menu form

Tags: forms, menu

```
<div class="grid_3">
  <h3>suzuki outboard range</h3>
  <form method="post" id="form1" class="form1">
       <label class="mb0">
        <span>Select from menu below</span>
        <select name="select">
          <option value="">Browse Portable Range</option>
          <option value="">Browse Midrange</option>
      <option value="">Browse Hi-Performance Range</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <div class="clear"></div>
       <a onClick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()"href="http://suzukimarine.com.au/outboards/portables/" target=_"blank" class="btn">          Search</a>
```

I need to add the 2 more url's to match the option values that appear in the drop down list. If I add the urls, it give me the extra submit buttons and I only want the 3 options from the menu with 1 submit button. I'm not real good at this stuff.

Comment: which do you prefer to put this in pure javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

put your urls in option value, and submit to the selected value, which is the url you put in

Comment: You are a legend, tnx for ur help mate.

Answer (score 0):

Submit form depend on control's name.If no name,not submit.
You may remove name of the select and add hidden to save select value.
Set value of the selected option  to hidden by JS.